# Cron is Creating in home directory instead of file directory

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash file to create a txt file (for the test), for example, but instead of creating the file in the Download folder, Is creating a file in the Home folder.

My bash file is from Download, also like this: /home/user/Downloads/myCron.sh.

Inside the bash file, I have a syntax here. Ex.

```
touch /home/user/Downloads/myFile.txt
```

Then I try to run to the terminal (ex. bash myCron.sh) and create a myFile.txt file in the Download Directory. This is my expectation.

But after applying the bash file to the CRON, like this:

```
 * * * * * /home/user/Downloads/myCron.sh
```

is creating the file in the Home folder instead of the Download folder.

What should I do?

Then I try to run to the terminal (ex. `bash myCron.sh`) and create a myFile.txt file in the Download Directory. This is my expectation.

Comment: Does the script actually use an explicit full path (`/home/user/Downloads/myFile.txt`), or just the filename (`myFile.txt`)? If you use just the filename, it'll be created in the script's "working directory", which is generally *not* the directory the script is in (and for cron jobs, it defaults to the user's home folder).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> * * * * * /home/user/Downloads/myCron.sh
> ```
>
> What should I do?

Tell `crond` to chdir to your favorite directory before exeucting.

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/Downloads && ./myCron.sh
```

Alternatively, you might choose to do that within the Bourne script.